# Remove all rows before row meeting condition in R

Tags: r

I am importing multiple excel files. The files have a non-standard structure, but all have the required data after a row of headers, midway down the rows of the data frame.

Here is a MWE:

```
df= structure(list(...1 = c("CPET Results", NA, "Operator", NA, NA, 
"Patient data", NA, "Administrative Data", "ID", "Title", "Last Name", 
"First Name", "Name Addition", "Sex", "Date of Birth", NA, NA, 
"Biological and Medical Baseline Data", "Height", "Weight", "Mask", 
"Race", "Body Fat", "Hip/Waist Ratio", "BMI", "Estimated Fitness Level", 
"BSA", "Hct", "Hb", "Medication that changes the Heart Rate", 
"Medication", "Existing Medical Conditions", NA, NA, NA, "Test data", 
"Start Time", "Duration", "CPET device", "Serial number", "Firmware version", 
"Flow Sensor", "Temperature", "Barometric Pressure", "Humidity", 
NA, NA, NA, "Variable", "V'O2", "V'CO2", "V'O2/kg", "V'O2/HR", 
"HR", "V'E/V'O2", "V'E/V'CO2", "V'E", "BF", "RER", "WR", NA, 
NA, "t", "h:mm:ss.ms", "0:00:25.000", "0:00:26.000", "0:00:27.000", 
"0:00:28.000", "0:00:29.000", "0:00:30.000"), ...2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Unit", 
"L/min", "L/min", "ml/min/kg", "ml", "/min", NA, NA, "L/min", 
"/min", NA, "W", NA, NA, "Phase", NA, "Rest", "Rest", "Rest", 
"Rest", "Rest", "Rest"), ...3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "343", NA, "GFRex", "343", NA, "female", "21/05/1924", NA, 
NA, NA, "178 cm", "88.2 kg", "Blue, medium", NA, NA, "0.96", 
"28", NA, "2.06 m2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "12/04/2021 11:27 AM", 
"0:15:12", "MetaLyzer 3B-R3", "231821624", "1.3.10", NA, "21.5°C", 
"1030mBar", "36%", NA, NA, NA, "Rest", "0.36", "0.31", "4", "0", 
"-", "35.7", "40.0", "14.9", "14", "0.88", "0", NA, NA, "Marker", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Unloaded Pedalling", 
"-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", NA, NA, 
"V'O2", "L/min", "0.61123179277253403", "0.61123179277253403", 
"0.61123179277253403", "0.61123179277253403", "0.51731964113453299", 
"0.51731964113453299"), ...5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Warm Up", "0.61", "0.47", 
"7", "0", "-", "26.2", "33.9", "18.5", "16", "0.77", "0", NA, 
NA, "V'O2/kg", "ml/min/kg", "6.9339965147196203", "6.9339965147196203", 
"6.9339965147196203", "6.9339965147196203", "5.8686289408341796", 
"5.8686289408341796"), ...6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VT1", "1.22", "0.98", "14", 
"-", "-", "28.6", "32.3", "35.4", "22", "0.88", "71", NA, NA, 
"V'O2/HR", "ml", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VT1 % Norm", 
"145", "-", "145", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "102", "-", "131", 
NA, NA, "HR", "/min", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...8 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VT1 % Max", 
"69", "55", "69", "-", "-", "83", "96", "54", "76", "87", "55", 
NA, NA, "WR", "W", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), ...9 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VT2", 
"1.71", "1.66", "19", "-", "-", "31.9", "32.7", "60.0", "32", 
"0.97", "122", NA, NA, "V'E/V'O2", NA, "30.6521809263484", "30.6521809263484", 
"30.6521809263484", "30.6521809263484", "34.760039405568897", 
"34.760039405568897"), ...10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VT2 % Norm", "203", "-", 
"203", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "147", "-", "226", NA, NA, "V'E/V'CO2", 
NA, "35.697970640705897", "35.697970640705897", "35.697970640705897", 
"35.697970640705897", "39.618822090063901", "39.618822090063901"
), ...11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "VT2 % Max", "97", "93", "97", "-", "-", "93", 
"97", "92", "110", "96", "96", NA, NA, "RER", NA, "0.858653317715381", 
"0.858653317715381", "0.858653317715381", "0.858653317715381", 
"0.87736175817015105", "0.87736175817015105"), ...12 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "V'O2peak", 
"1.77", "1.79", "20", "0", "-", "34.3", "33.8", "65.4", "29", 
"1.01", "128", NA, NA, "V'E", "L/min", "23.334937499999999", 
"23.334937499999999", "23.334937499999999", "23.334937499999999", 
"21.762284444444401", "21.762284444444401"), ...13 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "V'O2peak % Norm", 
"210", "-", "210", "0", "-", "-", "-", "-", "135", "-", "237", 
NA, NA, "VT", "L", "0.86250000000000004", "0.86250000000000004", 
"0.86250000000000004", "0.86250000000000004", "0.97866666666666702", 
"0.97866666666666702"), ...14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Normal", "0.84", "-", "10", 
"8", "104", "-", "-", "-", "22", "-", "54", NA, NA, "BF", "/min", 
"27.055", "27.055", "27.055", "27.055", "22.2366666666667", "22.2366666666667"
), ...15 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Absolute Maximum Values", "2.06", "1.96", "23", 
"0", "-", "44.5", "37.2", "73.5", "34", "1.19", "128", NA, NA, 
"V'CO2", "L/min", "0.52483620675725695", "0.52483620675725695", 
"0.52483620675725695", "0.52483620675725695", "0.45387646988174501", 
"0.45387646988174501"), ...16 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "WR", "W", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0")), row.names = c(NA, -70L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to remove all rows before `...1 == "t"`. I'm importing multiple files and want to do this to all of them at the sametime, and the header "t" appears at a different row number in each file.

I have tried

```
df1 = df[-c(1:row_number(df$...1 =="t")),]
df1 = df[-c(rownames(df[df$...1 =="t",])),]
```

I'd like a base R or dplyr solution. Thanks

Comment: `df[-seq(which(df[, '...1'] == 't')),]`

Comment: @onyambu, please post as answr?

Comment: Thanks @onyambu. I want to keep the row where `df$...1 =="t"` so have amended to `df1 = df[-c(1:which(df$...1 == "t")-1), ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **dplyr**, the `slice` function can be used to select rows by index, and the base-R `which()` can tell you which row index to start at.

```r
df %>%
  slice(min(which(...1 == 't')):n())
```

This code will check for any rows on which `...1 == 't'`, then `which()` tells you the row index. `min()` is in case you get a file with two rows of `'t'`. Then, the `slice` picks all rows from that row you just found to the end (`n()`).

Comment: `df[-c(1:which(df$...1 == "t")), ]`

Comment: Alternately, by the way, you could just load up the file, use which() to figure out which row you want to start on, then *re*-load the file using the result for the `skip` option of read_excel (or similar argument in whatever Excel-reading function you're using). This will save you the headache of having to fix all your header information.

Answer (score 2):

in base R you could do:

```
df[-seq(which(df[, '...1'] == 't') - 1),]
```